# NA coefficient in linear regression R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have to run a simulation with R.

Basically I have to create a set of variables (**X**) in a matrix nXp where the first variable has value 1, and the other 23 variables has random values randomly extracted from a N(0,1).
A vector **beta** of length 24 which has as first 2 values 1 and the rest is 0.
A vector **epsilon** of length 24 which is extracted from a N(0,1).
After that I create a variable **y** which is: **y=X %*% beta + epsilon**.
Then I select the variable of **X** which has the max(cor(abs(**Xj,y**))) where j goes from (3,24) and I have to run a model **y ~ X1 + X2 + Xj** and see the results.

```
> set.seed(123)
> 
> n=25 p=24 b=seq(1,1000)
> 
> X <- cbind(matrix(1,nrow=25,ncol=1),matrix(rnorm(25*23),nrow=25,
> ncol=23)) beta <- t(t(c(1,1,rep(0,22)))) eps <- t(t(rnorm(25)))
> 
> y <- X %*% beta + eps
> 
> j<-seq(3,24) m <- which.max(abs(cor(X[,j],y)))
> 
> newX <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,X[,1], X[,2], X[,m+2])) anyNA(newX[,2])
> mod <- lm(V1 ~ . , data=newX)
> summary(mod)

Call: lm(formula = V1 ~ ., data = newX)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.42575 -0.90957  0.06547  0.38879  2.39707  
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.1235     0.2421   4.641 0.000126 ***
V2                NA         NA      NA       NA    
V3            0.6803     0.2775   2.452 0.022612 *  
V4           -0.5943     0.3036  -1.957 0.063101 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.085 on 22 degrees of freedom Multiple R-squared:  0.3958,    
Adjusted R-squared:  0.3408  F-statistic: 7.205 on 2 and 22 DF,  p-value: 0.003919
```

Everything works fine, but as you can see the estimated coefficient for **V2**, that would be the coefficient for the variable **X1**, which is composed just by 1, is NA.
I don't understand why I have NA as a result, the values in the variable are listed as numeric and there's no missing value.

If anyone can help me to understand, thanks!

Comment: "variable X1, which is composed just by 1" The intercept is also represented by a column of 1 values in the design matrix. Thus, the `V2` effect and the intercept cannot be separated mathematically.

Comment: As a follow-up to @Roland s answer: Try to fit the model `mod <- lm(V1 ~ . -1, data=newX)` which removes the default intercept.